# How to programmatically get node ID in custom Rules Action

Tags: 7, nodes, rules, hooks

Need to create a custom Rules Action. How do I pragmatically get the node ID for an action such as when a node is saved?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameter node then you will get full node object into your action.

```
function MODULEname_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'CALLBACK_FUNCTION_NAME' => array(
      'label' => t('Send Mail to users for new content'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'node' => array('type' => 'node', 'label' => t('Current Node')),
      ),
      'group' => t('MODULE'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this accurate? I've tried it and I don't automatically get the node id.

Comment: Can you share your code so that I can understand it.

Comment: Please accept it as answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's not my question ¯\_(ツ)_/¯